# Laravel api call should return image url

Tags: laravel, image, api, url

I created a little API using Laravel, my doubt is where I should locate the images in the project and given a concrete API call how I return a URL to an image stored in my project?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: Static add folder path and concatenating name

Comment: Check in your filesytem.php what is the public path of the file then create url accordingly it could be in public folder or storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should return your image path like:**

First things is retrieve/static located the images folder path in the project.And then retrieve name of image from database using query. Finally Concatenating name of image which is stored in DB.

```
http://yourSite.com/folderPath.$imageName
```

Because when upload images, We have added only name of images not full URL.